# SQLSERVER 2008: Breaking a output for the entire day into 2 records for 12 hours

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking for the count of records as below.

PLANNED_SHIP_From_Date        PLANNED_SHIP_To Date       Total_Lines_Count  ....

1) 09-04-2016 07:00:01        09-04-2016 18:59:59       165         .....

2) 09-04-2016 19:00:00        10-04-2016 07:00:00       121         .....

3) 10-04-2016 07:00:01        10-04-2016 18:59:59       165         .....

4) 10-04-2016 19:00:00        11-04-2016 07:00:00       123         .....

5) 11-04-2016 07:00:01        11-04-2016 18:59:59       234         .....
.

Currently my query is counting the records as per date.

```
SELECT
   cast(shdr.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE as date),
   SUM(sdtl_1_1.TOTAL_LINES_COUNT) AS TOTAL_LINES_COUNT 
FROM
   dbo.SHIPMENT_HEADER AS shdr WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN
   (
      SELECT
         SHIPMENT_ID,
         COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_LINES_COUNT 
      FROM
         dbo.SHIPMENT_DETAIL AS SHIPMENT_DETAIL_1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
      WHERE
         (
            STATUS1 >= 401
         ) 
         AND (
            DATEDIFF(day, PLANNED_SHIP_DATE, CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME())) < 4
         ) 
      GROUP BY
         SHIPMENT_ID
   ) AS sdtl_1_1 
      ON sdtl_1_1.SHIPMENT_ID = shdr.SHIPMENT_ID 
WHERE
   (
      shdr.TRAILING_STS >= 401
   ) 
   AND (
      DATEDIFF(day, shdr.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE, CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME())) < 4
   ) 
GROUP BY
   cast(shdr.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE as date)
```

Comment: What is your current query? We will need some idea of your table schema to help. You should be able to `GROUP BY`different `DATEPART`s of whichever column you are generating `PLANNED_SHIP_DATE` from.

Comment: I am looking for the count of records as below.

From Date             To Date                 Count  .... other columns
10-04-2016 19:00:00   12-04-2016 07:00:00     123    .....
11-04-2016 07:00:01   12-04-2016 18:59:59     234    .....

Comment: What is the logic you are trying to apply to this `GROUP BY`? Do your twelve-hour periods run from 07:00 to 19:00?

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
DECLARE @ReportDays int = 30,
        @StartHr    int = 7,
        @Today      DATETIME2 = CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS DATE);

--http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/you-require-a-numbers-table.aspx
WITH 
    a AS (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 1),
    b AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM a AS x, a AS y),
    c AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM b AS x, b AS y),
    d AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM c AS x, c AS y),
    e AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM d AS x, d AS y),
    numbers as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS number FROM e),
    StartDates AS (
        SELECT
                DATEADD(
                    HH, 
                    @StartHr + (n2.number * 12),
                    DATEADD(D, 0-n1.number, @Today)
                ) AS StartDT
        FROM 
            (SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE Number BETWEEN 0 AND @ReportDays) n1
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE Number IN (0,1)) n2
        ),
    DateRanges AS 
    (SELECT StartDT, DATEADD(hh, 12, StartDT) AS EndDT FROM StartDates),
    Shipments AS 
    (SELECT
        StartDT AS PLANNED_SHIP_From_Date,
        EndDT AS PLANNED_SHIP_To_Date,
        1 AS Shipment
    FROM
        DateRanges dr
            LEFT JOIN dbo.SHIPMENT_DETAIL  sd
                ON sd.Status1 >=401
                AND sd.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE BETWEEN dr.StartDT AND dr.EndDT)
SELECT
    PLANNED_SHIP_From_Date,
    PLANNED_SHIP_To_Date,
    SUM(Shipment) AS TOTAL_LINES_COUNT
FROM
    Shipments
ORDER BY 
    PLANNED_SHIP_From_Date;
```

What we're doing is -

- Building a numbers table
- Using that to pull a list of days, with two records per day
- Working out the start & finish times for each time window
- Joining the time windows to the records and summing

Hope that helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add another column to your select....

```
CASE 
  WHENE DATEPART(HOUR, Planned_SHIP_DATE) < 12 THEN 'AM' ELSE 'PM'
END AS ShipPeriod
```

You could then add that column into a GROUPING to seperate the 'AM's  from 'PM's

Of course I have assuumed you wanted AM/PM.  But you can modify the CASE statement to break the hours up as you see fit.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping me out.

I have created a SQL query which worked for me. This query gives the count of records from morning 7 AM to 7 PM as MORNING_SHIFT count and 7PM to next day 7AM morning as EVENING_SHIFT for dates greater than 14 days in the past.

```
SELECT    

CASE
WHEN convert(VARCHAR(50), sh.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE, 120)  BETWEEN 
   (convert(VARCHAR(10), sh.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE, 120) + ' 07:00:00') AND 
   (convert(VARCHAR(10), sh.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE, 120) + ' 18:59:59')
THEN (CONCAT(cast(sh.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE as date),' ','morning_shift'))

WHEN convert(VARCHAR(50), sh.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE, 120)  BETWEEN 
   (convert(VARCHAR(10), sh.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE, 120) + ' 00:00:00') AND 
   (convert(VARCHAR(10), sh.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE, 120) + ' 06:59:59')
then (CONCAT(cast(DATEADD(DAY, -1, sh.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE) as date),' ','EVENING_shift'))
when
   convert(VARCHAR(50), DATEADD(DAY, -1, sh.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE) , 120)       BETWEEN (convert(VARCHAR(10), cast(DATEADD(DAY, -1, sh.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE) as date), 120) + ' 19:00:00') AND 
   (convert(VARCHAR(10), cast(DATEADD(DAY, -1, sh.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE) as date), 120) + ' 23:59:59')
THEN (CONCAT(cast(DATEADD(DAY, -1, sh.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE) as date),' ','EVENING_shift'))

END AS 'actual_date_time', sh.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE


FROM dbo.SHIPMENT_HEADER AS sh WITH (nolock)
WHERE (shdr.TRAILING_STS >= 401) AND (DATEDIFF(day, shdr.ACTUAL_SHIP_DATE_TIME, CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME())) < 14)
group by sh.ACTUAL_SHIP_DATE_TIME;
```